# What is the number of divisors with 2 distinct primefactors of a squarefree number W, where W divide their product?

Tags: combinatorics

Okay. This question is a bit tough to write in one sentence.

Let W be a squarefree number with n distinct prime factors.
Let ${W_1},{W_2},...{W_z}$
be all the squarefree numbers with exactly 2 distinct
prime factors which divide W.

Now I want all the combinations of products ${W_1} \cdot {W_2}...{W_k}$
such that W divides ${W_1} \cdot {W_2}...{W_k}$

As an example we have that $W = 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5$ where $n=3$

Let us call the number of combinations for C(n)
The combinations are :

$\left( {2 \cdot 3} \right) \cdot \left( {3 \cdot 5} \right),\left( {2 \cdot 5} \right) \cdot \left( {3 \cdot 5} \right),\left( {2 \cdot 3} \right) \cdot \left( {2 \cdot 5} \right),\left( {2 \cdot 3} \right) \cdot \left( {2 \cdot 5} \right) \cdot \left( {3 \cdot 5} \right)$

This is 4 combinations, so C(3)=4

I have found that C(4)=24

Now I noticed that
$4 = 1 \cdot {2^2}$
and $24 = \left( {1 + 2} \right) \cdot {2^3}$

So I speculate that C(n) will be $C(n) = {2^{n - 2}} \cdot \left( {n - 2} \right) \cdot \left( {n - 1} \right)$

Comment: Let me note this isn't really about primes. You have a set $S$ with $n$ elements; you have $T$, the set of all the $2$-element subsets of $S$; you want to know how many ways to pick elements of $T$ whose union is $S$.

Comment: I get $C(4)=41$. There's $12,34$; $13,24$; $14,23$; that's $3$ using two sets. There are $6\choose3$ which is $20$ ways to choose three sets, and the only ones that don't work are the ones like $12,13,14$, of which there are four, so $16$ that work. Every choice of four sets works; there are $15$. Every choice of five sets work; there are $6$. And using all six sets works. So, $3+16+15+6+1=41$.

Comment: It might be https://oeis.org/A006129

Comment: Care to engage with me, Kim?

Comment: Hi Gerry. You are right this is not about primes. At least not directly.

Comment: OK. Now: how about the answer I posted two days ago? Does it answer your question? Is there something more that you need?

Comment: I wanted a formula for the function C(n) which you gave with the expression :$$
a(n) = \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{n-k}\binom n k2^{\binom k 2}$$. You ask if there is something more I need. Yes, I also need a formula for the combinations which uses an odd number of sets minus the combinations which uses an even number of sets. In your comment for $$C(4)$$ you write  $$3 + 16 + 15 + 6 + 1$$,. By subtracting the even ones from the odd ones. we get : $$-3+16-15+6-1=3.$$

Comment: The "odd minus even" problem doesn't appear anywhere in your original post. Instead of putting it here in a comment where no one will see it, I suggest you post it as a new question (but linking each of the two posts to the other). Meanwhile, if you are satisfied that I have answered your original question, you can indicate that by clicking in the check mark next to my answer.

Comment: Ok. I did not see the checkmark option. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G$ be the complete graph on $n$ vertices.

Assign a different prime to each vertex of $G$. To each edge of $G$, assign the product of the primes at its ends. To each subgraph of $G$, assign the product of the numbers assigned to its edges. We want to know how many subgraphs of $G$ get assigned a multiple of the product of the $n$ primes. These are the subgraphs with no isolated vertices (vertices of degree zero).

The answer is tabulated at https://oeis.org/A006129 which, according to the comments on that page, counts "labeled graphs on $n$ unisolated nodes," equivalently, "the number of edge covers of the complete graph $K_n$." Starting with $n=2$, the first few numbers are $1, 4, 41, 768, 27449, 1887284, 252522481$ – you can see, they grow rapidly. Note that for $n=4$, the answer is $41$, not $24$.

The webpage contains references to the literature, computer programs, and the simple formula,
$$
a(n) = \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{n-k}\binom n k2^{\binom k 2}
$$
For example, $a(4)=(-1)^4{4\choose0}2^{0\choose2}+(-1)^3{4\choose1}2^{1\choose2}+(-1)^2{4\choose2}2^{2\choose2}+(-1)^1{4\choose3}2^{3\choose2}+(-1)^0{4\choose4}2^{4\choose2}$ $=1-4+12-32+64=41$.

The formula is easy to derive from the Principle of Inclusion-Exclusion. The total number of subgraphs of $G$ is $2^{n\choose2}$, since $G$ has $n\choose2$ edges, and each edge has the choice of whether or not to be in the subgraph. From this we must subtract, for each vertex, the number of subgraphs with that vertex isolated; that's $n2^{n-1\choose2}$. Then, for each pair of vertices, we have to add back in the number of subgraphs with that pair isolated; that's ${n\choose2}2^{n-2\choose2}$. And so on, leading to
$$
2^{n\choose2}-n2^{n-1\choose2}+{n\choose2}2^{n-2\choose2}\cdots=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k{n\choose k}2^{n-k\choose2}
$$